# How to define boost::any operator ==

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to define `operator ==` for `boost::any` in my project. Since the arguments belong to the `boost` namespace, this is where argument-dependent lookup will search for it. So, the signature is:

```
namespace boost
{
    bool operator == (const boost::any &, const boost::any &);
}
```

However, this generates ambiguous overload errors whenever I include a boost library that compares enums for equality, such as `thread/locks.hpp` — the compiler sees no reason to prefer converting the enums to `int` and using the built-in comparison instead of converting them to `boost::any` and using mine.

I can hack around this by also including any such libraries in the same file as my comparator and defining custom operators for comparing boost's enums. But there got to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace boost {
  template<class T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, any>{}, bool>::type =true
  >
  bool operator == (const T& lhs, const T& rhs){
    return any_equal(lhs, rhs);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: Slight side note that it's questionable to open up the `boost` namespace for custom additions.

Comment: @sehe yes; I would create my own extended namespace `namespace myboost { struct any: ::boost::any { /* some glue code */ };}`